# The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat8

I has been writing java web-app using the servlets+jsp, JDBC, and tomcat how a servlet container. When I connect to the database and trying to get some data, i given a current exception : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHMPn.png)

Project structure : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyMVA.png)

DataSource code :

```
public class LibraryDataSource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LibraryDataSource.class);

    private LibraryDataSource() {}

    public static DataSource getLibraryDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource libraryDatasource = new PGSimpleDataSource();

        try(FileReader propertiesReader =
                    new FileReader("src/main/resources/application.properties")) {

            Properties databaseProperties = new Properties();
            databaseProperties.load(propertiesReader);
            libraryDatasource.setURL(databaseProperties.getProperty("postgresUrl"));
            libraryDatasource.setUser(databaseProperties.getProperty("postgresUser"));
            libraryDatasource.setPassword(databaseProperties.getProperty("postgresPassword"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.info("LibraryDataSource::getLibraryDataSource : ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.info("LibraryDataSource::getLibraryDataSource : ", e);
        }

        return libraryDatasource;
    }
}
```

BookDAO method where the error detected :

```
@Override
    public List<Book> getAll() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            Statement getAllStatement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = getAllStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Book");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setId(resultSet.getLong(1));
                book.setTitle(resultSet.getString(2));
                book.setYear(resultSet.getInt(3));
                book.setQuantity(resultSet.getInt(4));
                book.setAuthors(resultSet.getString(5));

                books.add(book);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return books;
    }
```

Comment: In my case, the package name of the Flyway configuration file was not being recognized as spring bean, fixed the package name and it worked

Answer (score 18):

I hope it's not too late.
I fixed this in my project just assigning a password to the database user, in my case 'postgres'.

```
ALTER USER "postgres" WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

And in your application.properties file you must have something like (I'm using postgreSQL):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

P. D: I'm new in Stack Overflow. I hope I could have helped.

Answer (score 2):

spring.datasource.password = ***your_password***

You just have to check if that line of code is active in your application.properties or not commented out. Then you are good to run the project again.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this in my project by just assigning a password to the database user, in my case 'postgres'